# Using the same name more than once?

Tags: fiction, naming, comics

So in my story, theres a character (name's Tris) in love with a girl, but she died. Her name was Lais.

Later when he's older, he saves a little girl who looks the same as the girl who dies. He adopts her and re-names her Lais, after the girl who died.

Is this a little messed up? There's more,

In between these two situations (the two Lais's) Tris is acquainted with another girl, he talks to her about the first Lais, and realises that this girl is in love with her, and is jealous of Lais (she's unaware that she is dead).

He runs away from her, but she finds him, and starts going by the name Lace - similar to Lais, this girl is a bit crazy.

The way the story is written, Lace meets the second Lais a few times while chasing Tris, then readers learn about the first Lais.

Basically the two Lais's and the Lace are all in the story at the same time, is this too confusing?

It's actually a comic, so they would all be shown, and they would look different.

Also the value of the name Lais is an integral part of the story but is it just too much?

The existence of the first Lais isn't revealed until near the end, so I've realised that by the time this happens readers should be used to the Lais that was introduced first. The three of them are only in the story at the same for a short while, and any confusion should *hopefully* be brief, and helped by the visuals :)

Comment: maybe you should have called her maze :)

Comment: For a comic it might work, but personally I hate having to sort out names. I like them all to begin with different letters when reading.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It makes a *huge* difference that it's a comic. Seeing the visual cue of how the character is drawn will go 90% of the way towards dispelling any confusion, particularly if we only see child Lais and adult Lace.

It is possible to have a written text with similar or identical names and have it be a plot point, like V.C. Andrews's *My Sweet Audrina,* but you have to be very careful in pulling it off.

Comment: Whether that’s “messed up” depends on your character’s motivation.
Can you describe how Tris, acquainted with a girl, talks about and realises "she" is jealous of Lais?
As your story is described, Lace is in no way crazy.
As you put it, two Lais's and Lace could only be confusing.


What do you mean by “Also the value of the name Lais is an integral part of the story but is it just too much?” 
Whenever the existence of the first Lais was revealed, how could you demand readers should be used to the Lais introduced first?
Any confusion should hopefully be cleared up by you.